# Macro from Excel Cells to Powerpoint tables

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm attempting to take values from Excel cells and populate PowerPoint text tables.

Below is what I have thus far leveraging a previous macro, but I am not sure that I am on the right track.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sourceXL As Excel.Application
    Dim sourceBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim myPres As Presentation
    Dim row_excel As Integer
    Dim construindo As Integer
    Dim mantidos As Integer
    Dim contador As Integer
    Dim numero As Integer
    Dim chave As Integer


    Set sourceXL = Excel.Application
    Set sourceBook = sourceXL.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Value)
    Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets(4)
    Set myPres = ActivePresentation

    row_excel = Int(TextBox4.Value)
    construindo = Int(TextBox3.Value)
    mantidos = Int(TextBox5.Value)

    chave = 0

    If construindo = myPres.Slides.Count Then
        chave = 1
    End If

    While sourceSheet.Cells(row_excel, 1) <> "" 'loop for row in excel source

        myPres.Slides(construindo).Shapes(3).Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sourceSheet.Cells(row_excel, 2)
        myPres.Slides(construindo).Shapes(3).Table.Cell(4, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sourceSheet.Cells(row_excel, 5)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(construindo).Duplicate
        construindo = construindo + 1

        row_excel = row_excel + 1

    Wend

    numero = myPres.Slides.Count

    If numero > construindo Then
        For contador = 1 To (numero - construindo - mantidos + 1)
            myPres.Slides(construindo).Delete
        Next contador
    End If

    If chave = 1 Then
        myPres.Slides(myPres.Slides.Count).Delete
    End If

    sourceBook.Close

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

---

run time error 13 :Type Mismatch

[image]

Comment: Does this give an error?  If yes, what is the message and which line causes it? Otherwise, is it not behaving as you expect? ie. what's your actual question?

Comment: This was pulled from another macro that is essentially serving the same purpose of populating tables in ppt. I am trying to leverage the code to populate data from my excel sheet and populate into my own ppt presentation. I am getting a run time error 13 :Type Mismatch

Comment: " I am getting a run time error 13 :Type Mismatch "   At what line?

Comment: What value is in textbox3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like TextBox3.Value is empty or has text in it... the function Int() throws an error if you pass a string. You can check the value like this:

```
if not isnumeric(TextBox3.Value) then
    MsgBox "You have to enter a number!"
else
    construindo = Int(TextBox3.Value)
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Int takes a number as an argument and converts by truncating rather than rounding.

CInt takes a number or a string that "looks like" a number, so might be preferable here.

And if the passed value may contain non-numeric text, this can help

Debug.Print CInt(Val("12345xyz"))